# Route53 Nameに合ったIDを取りたいが、存在しないものが表示される

Tags: aws, amazon-route53

以下のコマンドで `--dns-name` に合うIDを取得したいと考えています。
ですが、この例でいう `augment.site` のIDを取得したくても他の存在しないIDが返ってきてしまい困っています。

コマンドが悪いのかバグなのかよくわかりませんが、ご知見のある方、アドバイスを頂けないでしょうか。宜しくお願い致します。

**実行したコマンド:**

```
aws --profile myplofile route53 list-hosted-zones-by-name --dns-name augment.site | jq -r ".HostedZones[0].Id"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

「存在しないIDが返ってきてしま」うのはちょっと想像できません。

> ```
> aws --profile myplofile route53 list-hosted-zones-by-name --dns-name augment.site | jq -r ".HostedZones[0].Id"
> ```

で意図しない結果が得られるのであれば

```
aws --profile myplofile route53 list-hosted-zones-by-name --dns-name augment.site
```

を実行すれば、何が返ってきているのか確認できると思います。その内容を見て冷静に判断されてはどうでしょうか。

---

> 存在するIDが返ってきてました。複数個出てくるのは謎です。

AWSCLIの[`list-hosted-zones-by-name`](https://awscli.amazonaws.com/v2/documentation/api/latest/reference/route53/list-hosted-zones-by-name.html)およびその元になっている[`ListHostedZonesByName`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/APIReference/API_ListHostedZonesByName.html) APIを確認しました。

> Retrieves a list of your hosted zones in lexicographic order.

とあり、引数に指定したDNS Nameでフィルタリングするわけではなく、DNS Name順に並べたhosted zoneの一覧を返すようです。ですので、特定のhosted zone idを得たいのであればクライアント側でフィルタリングする必要があるのかもしれません。例えば`example.com`のhosted zone idを得るにはこんな感じでしょうか。

```
aws --profile myplofile route53 list-hosted-zones \
  --query 'HostedZones[?Name==`example.com.`].Id' --output text
```

Comment: コメントありがとうございます。コマンドを実行して、見つけたことは".site"とつくものがピックアップされて出てきているようです。

Comment: @user39728 その反応だと、存在しないIDが返ってくるという状態からは進展して、存在するIDが返ってきていたのでは？ あとは引数に指定した名前にtypo等はないですか？

Comment: コメントありがとうございます。はい、存在するIDが返ってきてました。複数個出てくるのは謎です。typoはしてませんでした。

Comment: コメントありがとうございます。ご教示頂いたコマンドを試してみたのですが、HostedZones[?Name==`example.com.`].Id
HostedZones[?Name==`example.com.`].Id
HostedZones[?Name==`example.com.`].Id
といった返り方でした。あと少しだと思うのですが、どうすれば良いかご検討はつきますでしょうか。。。

Comment: @user39728 それらの違いも一覧を見ればわかるのでは？ private hosted zoneを複数作ってるとかそういう。